# Why am I getting this warning while running the qiskit command IBMQ.load_account()?

Tags: qiskit

I'm getting this warning:

```
C:\Users\XYZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\models\backendconfiguration.py:337: UserWarning: `dt` and `dtm` now have units of seconds(s) rather than nanoseconds(ns).
  warnings.warn('`dt` and `dtm` now have units of seconds(s) rather '
```

Can you please help me understand this?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please clarify what is your problem.

Comment: Would it be possible to [edit] a minimal (not) working example of code into this, so that we have some context to go from? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a warning to let you know that the API has changed for the backend configurations such as [PulseBackendConfiguration](https://qiskit.org/documentation/api/qiskit.providers.models.PulseBackendConfiguration.html). The `dt` (qubit drive channel timestep) and `dtm` (measurement drive channel timestep) parameters were previously specified in nanoseconds, but they are now specified in seconds. If you're not doing anything so advanced as to directly use these parameters, you can safely ignore the warning.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress those warnings?